# .NET MVC 3 Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I use Entity framework for creating model.
I have table hierarchy where User is my base table and I have tables Lecturer and Student which have some specific data in them. Entity framework made model that it isn't suitable so I made my middle layer called modelview where I have student table which wraps all data from both user and student tables. I have made CRUD functionality for students but I only want that admin can create student with some initial password, than admin should not have option to change student password at Edit action.
The problem is that password is required field at student Create action so I set [Required] attribute to it, but at Edit I must not have password field and my ModelState.IsValid is then always false since password field in this case isn't present and therefore is null.
I thought on adding hidden password field, but that would be very bad since someone could look at page source and see password value.
Can I somehow once this field required and another time not required?
If you have any other idea that might help please share with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user is being edited, you can put in a placeholder hidden field, with the value ***** (or something like that). This will satisfy the `Required` attribute - you just have to make sure you don't update the password when the user is edited :)

Comment: This sound like valid solution :), I'll just wait a while if someone has maybe more elegant solution.

Comment: I tried part with * password and than to set regular one:
user.Password = Entities.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == student.ID).Password;
but then it crashes on: Entities.Users.Attach(user);
But, if I hard code like this:
user.Password = "somePass"; Then it updates user and student tables regulary. This looks impossible to me.

Comment: "`user.Password = Entities.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == student.ID).Password`" - are you building a new `User` object every time, then? I think you'd be better off getting the appropriate `User` from the `Entities` (`User userToUpdate = Entities.Users.Single(u => u.UserId == userViewModel.UserId)`), updating only the properties you want to update (`userToUpdate.Name = userViewModel.Name`), then calling `Entities.SaveChanges()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve, I just didn't knew that EF works like this. Now I can use hidden password field and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could randomly generate a password and not have it be required at all.

Or you could remove the requred attribute and manually check if it's present at the serverside.

```
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Password))
            ModelState.AddModelError("Password","A password is required");
```

To validate clientside, if you're using jquery validation: [JQuery Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation)

Comment: Auto generation on password in not an option.
I thought about removing [Required] attribute adn to place required validator only on create page but I don't know how to place required validator.

Answer (score 0):

If you have separate views for `Student` addition and editing, an alternative solution would be:

1. Create a `StudentViewModel` class which contains all the properties required for both `Student` addition and editing, and
2. Create a `StudentAdditionViewModel` class (optionally derived from `StudentViewModel`) which includes a `Password` property.

You can then use `StudentAdditionViewModel` as the Add view's model, and `StudentViewModel` as the edit view's model :)

Comment: I thought about that too, but this will make my application much more complex